# Use of apostrophe in days?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Is it:

> As Lilly lay down tucked up in her bed, all the days events span round in her head.

or

> As Lilly lay down tucked up in her bed, all the day’s events span round in her head.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why you think each one might be correct?

Answer (score 5):

*Spun* round is correct, as is *all the day’s events*.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Dunno why there’s such a persistent aversion to strong verbs whose inflected forms have a *u* in them, but there really seems to be. 
A reasonably complete list of the verbs that have no *u* in their present tense but which do (or at least, can; I discarded the obsolete forms, but some archaics & duals remain) have a *u* in either their past or past participle are: *begin, beseech, bestick, bework, bring, dare, drink, fling, ping, ring, seek, shall, shrink, sing, sink, slink, sneak, spin, spring, stick, sting, strike, string, swim, swing, teach, will,* and *wring.*

Answer (score 0):

The use of the apostrophe in *day’s* is correct, as you are referring to all of the events of the day.  Likewise, saying *all of today’s events* is also correct.